# List with function, how to understand how new list created

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How does this code work?. It creates a new list that doesn't affect the original list in the code?

```
def changeit(lst):
    lst[0] = "Michigan"
    lst[1] = "Wolverines"
    return lst

mylst = ['106', 'students', 'are', 'awesome']
newlst = changeit(list(mylst))
print(mylst)
print(newlst)
```

Comment: Is this part of your homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) documentation will be of assistance here.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question?

Comment: Basically this isn't homework.  But trying to understand how lists are affected when changed in functions.  Lists are object, right?  So how come this code doesn't affect the values with the original list 'mylst', that is passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the `list([iterable])` constructor is called here:

```
newlst = changeit(list(mylst))
```

It constucts a new list object in memory. If you remove it, then you will have the output:

```
>>> newlst = changeit(mylst)
>>> print(mylst)
>>> print(newlst)

['Michigan', 'Wolverines', 'are', 'awesome']
['Michigan', 'Wolverines', 'are', 'awesome']
```

Comment: So list(mylst), makes a copy?

Comment: Yes, `list()` creates a new (empty) list, but `list(mylst)` creates a new list, but with the same contents as `mylst`. Also `newlst = changeit(mylst[:])` would again be the same because `mylst[:]` also copies `mylst`.

Comment: In this specific case, yes - it copies. In [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)), a constructor (which `list()` is), creates a new object based on its arguments. `list()` is set up such that it copies elements from any iterable passed to it (e.g. tuple).

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping `mylst` in another `list()` function creates a new object rather than applying the operations to the original list object.

Note this would not work, for example, if the list contained sub-lists - operations done on the sub-lists would also affect the sub-lists in the original list.

[deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) could be used for lists with sub-lists.

Comment: "would not work" IMHO this does not make much sense, as it's not "working" as intended to begin with. "would not be the case" might be better, although it _would_ be the case just the same if OP changed the top-level elements.

Comment: I assumed that the OP's code was working as he expected, but he was unsure why.

Answer (score -1):

- I will give you one hint.
- As you can see in case when you just simply assign it to another variable they both are pointing to same object in this case `mylst` and `a` are pointing to same object so modifying either one will change other.
- In case of `b` when you use `list` function it creates new object of `mylst`. You can varify this by comparing id of `mylst`,`a` and `b`

```
mylst = ['106', 'students', 'are', 'awesome']
a = mylst # reference of mylst
b = list(mylst) # copy of mylst

print(id(mylst) == id(a))
print(id(mylst) == id(b))
```

output:

```
True
False
```